# Cordova: Create socket server

Tags: android, cordova, sockets, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I want to make a chat mobile app with corodva, I want to transmit messages from phone to another phone directly **without a server in the middle**.
So I'm thinking about a socket communication throught a socket server on one of the phones and exchanging messages directly.
Is there a way to create a socket server with cordova like in Java ServerSocket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, use the chrome socket plugin:

[cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp)

The point is, the documentation is not very easy, but the plugin is working very well.

I'm using it for a private app [Rezepte](http://www.unbelievable-good-apps.de/rezepte/). Sorry, the site is not finished.