# communication between multiple phones/devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I would like to create an application where near phones/devices can send data between each other.

it should look like that all devices except one turn on some listening function. One device create game and add each of devices from list to game.

I know how to accomplish this task with use of intermediary server. But I would like to achieve this in a different way without server. For example I can create app which find near ibeacons and displays them in a list, and get data from them. Is it possible to make to way communication by bluetooth between phones with bluetooth?

Maybe other technologies? I do not want to use NFC, because range is to short.
Another limitation is that, this solution should be an cordova/phonegap plugin?

Edit:
I need to communicate between users devices. For example I want to make app where two users standing near each other chat together. Messages should be send between phones, without server.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351164/cordova-create-socket-server/31352209#31352209

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like iBeacons is the perfect solution for what you're attempting to achieve. It doesn't require NFC or a server–only devices that have Bluetooth 4.0 LE (Low Energy).

If you're unhappy with iBeacons, I recommend the Multipeer Connectivity framework that also became available in iOS7:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/

Here's a good tutorial on AppCoda:

http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/

Another benefit to using the Multipeer Connectivity framework as opposed to iBeacons, is that it doesn't require Bluetooth 4.0 LE, which isn't available on iPad 2 and iPhone 4 devices.

Comment: Thanks for answer. it is possible that my question was imprecise. I need to communicate between users devices. For example I want with You to chat. Messages should be send between our phones, without server. I will add this comment to my question to be more precise.